# Bug while Swapping a LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here I am trying to Swap the Head and tail of a singly Linked list

```
 public void reversePI() {
        Node N1 = this.tail;
        Node Helper = this.head.next;
        this.tail = this.head;
        this.tail.next = null;
        this.head = N1;
        this.head.next = Helper;
        this.display();
    }
```

Here is the further Approach for the above function to explain my way of thinking.
Let us assume we have a Link list as

```
4k(adress) 1(data)-->5k(adress) 2(data)-->6k(adress) 3(data)-->7k(adress) 4(data)-->null
```

we have a code

now when the first line executes

```
N1= 7k(adress) 4(data)

Helper=5k(adress) 2(data)

this.tail=4k(adress) 1(data)
```

at this point the list should be

```
  5k(adress) 2(data)-->6k(adress) 3(data)-->4k(adress) 1(data)-->5k(adress) 2(data)
```

now we set the tail as null to break the initial link

```
this.tail.next = null;

5k(adress) 2(data)-->6k(adress) 3(data)-->4k(adress) 1(data)-->null
```

now     this.head = N1;

```
7k(adress) 4(data)  5k(adress) 2(data)-->6k(adress) 3(data)-->4k(adress) 1(data)-->null
```

after this         this.head.next = Helper; line will establish the link and

```
7k(adress) 4(data)--> 5k(adress) 2(data)-->6k(adress) 3(data)-->4k(adress) 1(data)-->null
```

is my Approch correct or is there something I am missing that leads to generating an infinite  output while running the display method -->

```
public void display() {
            Node current = this.head;
            while (current != null) {
                System.out.print(current.data + " ");
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to handle the second last node's next, it should point to the new tail, but it is still pointing to the old tail which is the new head. This results in a loop: head -> ... -> secondLastNode -> head